# How to secure java class by spring programatically

Tags: java, spring

How to securing my Java page programatically using Spring

```
@Secured({"ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"})  
public class SecretClass extends BasePage {
    // do work
}
```

But I want to do it programatically, get role from db first and put it.

```
public class SecretClass extends BasePage {
    // Something like:
    // String role = userManager.getRole();

    // @Secured({"ROLE_USER", role})
    @InjectService("UserManager")
    private UserManager userManager;
}
```

But, I know you can't do like that with @Secured, so is there any way to do what I want by code? For securing whole page, not particular method.

Answer (score 0):

read about spring security it will give u the required features which you want for your application more secured. https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using the framework and not implementing (and testing) your own code especially in security context.

But if you really need to implement your own logic, you should take a look at @PreAuthorize . @Secured is an old annotation and kind of deprecated since @PreAuthorize can do much more and uses the spring expression language.
In our Project we used @PreAuthorize(hasPermission(...)) and implemented our own logic within hasPermission(). But this might be an overkill for you, since @PreAuthorize can already do a lot!

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/el-access.html).